# Why is this question unclear (and why is it deleted)?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, deleted-questions

[This question asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460222/get-the-row-at-60-of-the-table) "Get the row at 60% of the table".  This seems pretty straightforward. If the table has 100 rows, return the 60th row. If it has 500 rows, return the 300th row.

For the non-10k users, here is the entire question:

> ### Get the row at 60% of the table
>
> I'd like to go to the 60% row in a table with oracle. I can find the
>   number of the 60% row with:
>
> ```
> select round(count(*)*0.60) as sira from (select to_date(time) as tarih,lenght as hiz  from table order by length desc)
> ```
>
> i.e I'll get **name** column data from table which row number.NOte:I
>   will get name data after I ordering my table with `order by length
>   desc`
>
> [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle)

I was surprised when the question was initially closed, but now it has been deleted by a moderator.  Why is this question considered "unclear", and why was it worthy of a moderator-delete?

Comment: Yes , it should not be deleted. Looks clear enough to me.

Comment: I completely understand why it got closed (and I'm not really sure what exactly is being asked), but deletion does indeed seem weird. Could have been flagged, possibly by the OP. Maybe.

Comment: Not unclear, not lack of research or minimal understanding. May need some rewording, but weird none the less.

Comment: If ever you are surprised when a question is closed, your immediate response should be to edit it. You understand both the question and the rules of the site, and when a question is closed you may be the only intersection of those two sets. Fix it so that others can understand it, and it may re-open.

Comment: Can someone who understands what the question is please explain it? He says he'd like to get such and such a row from a table, then immediately shows a query to identify the row in the table. So what exactly does he want from us?

Comment: The question is indeed not very clear. The query he shows, returns the number of the row he wants to retrieve, not the actual row. The OP wants the data of that row. I too find it not really reasonable to delete this question. I don't know Oracle, but I would use a cursor for that.

Comment: I don't know why it was closed (I think I understand the question, and I know nothing about databases). But once it had been closed for months, it was perfectly normal to delete it. Deletion is the normal fate for questions that have been closed for long enough that it is clear that nobody is motivated to improve them into reopenability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was indirectly flagged this morning (by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), due to three consecutive closed questions by the same user).  I noticed that the question had been closed for over three months without being edited and without any votes to reopen, so I deleted it.  I've undeleted it since you edited the question.

Comment: Multiple close votes seem normal if someone is following the close vote review queue?  Those votes were months old though.

Comment: @Andomar I don't follow you. The question was asked on May 9 and closed on May 10. The close votes didn't linger in the queue for months.

Comment: I probably misunderstand what you mean by "indirectly flagged this morning (due to multiple closed questions in a short time by the same user)".  Did you mean other questions from Selçuklu Ebrar were closed recently?

Comment: @Andomar Yes. We get a flag in the queue (from the system) when a user has multiple closed questions. We will often take a look at their [closed] questions to see if any can be rehabilitated or if they ought to be deleted outright.

Comment: @Andomar See my (hopefully clarifying) edit, and George's comment.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why BillTheLizard deleted it, so the following is only 'what I would do in his place'.

- The question was closed on May 10.  The OP did not do anything to improve the question for *three months*.
- The question, as written, *has no potential to help other people*. By the close votes, we can see that a good number of the community can't figure out what was being asked.  How can we expect that question to help others?
- None of the 5 people who voted to close, nor the answer-er, decided to edit the question into shape *for three months*.

I have a few issues with the question as it's currently written that keep me from undeleting it or unilaterily re-opening it:

- The Title is very unclear (60% of a row? What does that even mean?)
- The expected output is not there; what does the user expect to get from the query?
- sample input is missing (table data)

I'll be happy to undelete the question if you put an edit together to help solve these problems.  Without some interest from you or the OP (or any other community member) in fixing the question, I can't see the benefit in undeleting it.

Due to the above factors, this question is eligible for deletion. Whether it's community deleted or moderator deleted is irrelevant.  Since you have some skin in the game, perhaps you can suggest an edit to improve the question to get it undeleted and possibly re-opened?

Comment: I already edited the question at `May 9 at 11:18`.  By then the question probably had a close vote, and thus attracted more close votes from the Close Votes review queue.  Not sure why the question is vague, it seems fairly clear to me.

Comment: @Andomar I wouldn't automatically assume a question was closed just because it was in the close vote queue.  I've seen plenty of examples where questions in the Close vote queue are left open.  I have a few immediate problems with that question that would keep me from unilaterily re-opening it: The Title is very unclear. The expected output is not there; what does the user expect to get from the query? Sample input is missing (e.g., with this input, and me wanting '60% of a row', and the expected output, what's going wrong?).